# Parse date format of type d.M.yyyy

Tags: java

I have a strange date format (e.g 3.4.2021 -> d.M.yyyy the zeros are skipped) and I would like to get a string of format dd.MM.yyyy but all I tried until now throws an exception and says that text could not be parsed.

One of the examples that I've tried:

```
String d = LocalDate.parse(startDatePannel).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yyyy"));
```

How can I parse this date?

Comment: You need to *parse* with the existing pattern, and *format* with the pattern you want. So the `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d.M.yyyy")` part belongs in the *parse* operation. (I would start off by not formatting at all - get the parse operation working, then work on formatting. I'd also avoid doing it all in a single line, as that makes it harder to debug.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, makes perfect sense what you said and solved my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [comment by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798251/pare-date-format-of-type-d-m-yyyy/68798337#comment121585855_68798251).

Define a formatting pattern matching your input.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterIn = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d.M.uuuu" ) ;
```

Parse.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "23.1.2021" , formatterIn ) ;
```

Define a formatting pattern for desired output.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterOut = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) ;
```

Generate text representing the value of your `LocalDate` object.

```
String output = localDate.format( formatterOut ) ;
```

Comment: You was right guys. I was mixing up things, because of inlining statements. Now works as it should. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Adrian As you’ve learned, excessive method-chaining and method-nesting leads to error-prone code. Using short simple separate statements makes your code easier to read and debug… and can often make it easier for the compiler and JIT to optimize your code, a nice bonus. Use method-chaining and method-nesting where it makes your code *easier* to reason about, not more difficult.